# Modular android app without RX java or RX android

Tags: android, design-patterns, rx-java2, android-mvp, android-architecture

I had gone through this github app,
[Buffer app GitHub Link](https://github.com/bufferapp/clean-architecture-koin-boilerplate)

I loved this project and devoted my lot of time to understand it quite nicely. But the only problem is that i want to do it without RX java,

I am trying to understand my questions,

In the domain section, Rxjava is the thing which redirects the result from respective data source to corresponding source or presenter for success or Error

So, I only want to understand how can I do it without RXJava? It will be great if you guys can provide me some sample app. with same modular architecture or how can we achieve it with same github app(will prefer this one).

I just want to know, how can we replace RX with custom listener or Minimal code, so that it can map listener to corresponding datasource or vice versa to presenter once data is received.

I had also opened an Issue on this GitHub app, with following url,
[My Open issue in this app.](https://github.com/bufferapp/clean-architecture-koin-boilerplate/issues/4)

but I think developer is little busy.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There's also EventBus library or Otto, but the rewriting your own listener/publisher interfaces sounds like a lot of work

Comment: I just want to understand the concept, how can I do it without RX java, if you can provide me some open source project,  it will be lot easy for me.

Comment: Unfortunately asking for off site resources is considered off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: Can u please let me know, where should I ask these type of question?

Comment: Github is good enough. Otherwise, I feel like the official repos by Google are a fine starting point.  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components

Comment: Yes, it is but it it didn't have separated modularisation like buffer app